# How to set back RStudio to global default working directory?

Tags: rstudio

In the General R Options of RStudio, in the option `Default working directory (when not in a project):`, previous to set for the first time a specific directory appears this symbol `~` that means No directory or Global default working directory, like here: [image]

My problem is that I set the directory to *My documents* folder, and I can't set it back to `~` because the `Browse`button doesn't allow it.  Do you know how can I set it back to `~`?

I would like to do that because in my new scripts I'm changing always this directory to other paths with the `setwd()` function. But when I close RStudio all the objects from my workspace are saved in this new directory set with `setwd()`, then I have to save manually every time my workspace to *My documents* directory. Therefore, I prefer to change it to Global default working directory `~`, and I can't find how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For PC, go to your RStudio user-settings file location (Note you may have to show hidden folders in your folder options settings):

C:\Users[your name]\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop\monitored\user-settings

Edit your RStudio with Notepad, change or delete the directory.

Here is what you probably have:
initialWorkingDirectory="C:/Users/[your name]/Documents"

Change to:
initialWorkingDirectory="~"

Hope that helps.