# How to set Rstudio default working directory back to global default

Tags: rstudio

I just got myself into the same predicament that this user did 4 years ago:
[How to set back RStudio to global default working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594993/how-to-set-back-rstudio-to-global-default-working-directory)
(there is no way to re-enter a "~" using the UI), and the line of code described by the answer (initialWorkingDirectory=) no longer appears to exist in the user-settings file.

Can I find this in a different file somewhere in the Rstudio folder, or is there a different line in the user-settings file I can edit?

Thank you!

Comment: ~ is just a short cut for something like `/home/username/` or `/Users/username/` why not just set it to that?

Comment: Thanks - I was misunderstanding what it did. I assumed the ~ caused the wd to default to whatever directory a script was opened in, but I see now that still happens, even with my default set to something else. My mistake! Thanks for you help :)